# Flask manage.py create_db command throwing import error for nonexistent module

Tags: python, flask

I have a Flask application that I am trying to connect and set up a Postgres DB for within a Docker container alongside Nginx. These three component set up fine and I have no errors with the Docker logs.

The issue I am having is that when I run the Flask cli command to set up my database I am getting an import error.

What I don't understand is the fact that the import Python can't find (`web`) is actually the folder that the remainder of the app and config files sit in, whereas `app` is what is referenced in my `manage.py` and contains the relevant `__init__.py`.

This is what my folder structure looks like for the web app component.

```
└── web
    ├── app
    │   ├── config.py
    │   ├── controllers
    │   ├── forms
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── models
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   ├── routes
    │   ├── static
    │   └── templates
    ├── dev-requirements.txt
    ├── Dockerfile
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── manage.py
    ├── requirements.txt
    └── scripts
        └── run.sh
```

But when I run `python manage.py create_db` I get the below error.

```
/app $ ls
Dockerfile            dev-requirements.txt  scripts
__init__.py           manage.py
app                   requirements.txt

/app $ python manage.py create_db
Usage: manage.py create_db [OPTIONS]
Try 'manage.py create_db --help' for help.

Error: Could not import 'app.web'.
/app $
```

This is my `manage.py`

```
from flask.cli import FlaskGroup

from app import app, db

cli = FlaskGroup(app)


@cli.command("create_db")
def create_db():
    db.drop_all()
    db.create_all()
    db.session.commit()


@cli.command("drop_db")
def drop_db():
    db.drop_all()
    db.session.commit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cli()
```

I noticed that when I remove `__init__.py` from my application root (`web`) I get:

```
Error: Could not import 'web'.
```

And when `__init__.py` is left in the application root  and I try to run `manage.py` from the `app` folder I get:

```
/app/app $ python ../manage.py create_db
Usage: manage.py create_db [OPTIONS]
Try 'manage.py create_db --help' for help.

Error: Could not import 'app.app.web'. # this
```

What is odd here is that Flask seems to think the `web` 'module' sits below `app` in the folder structure.

There is obviously something going on with my imports, but I can't see what it is that I have configured incorrectly.

I did try changing the `manage.py` import to: `from .app import app, db` with the leading `.` but I got import exceptions.

All imports are based off of `app.foo`.

What have I missed or screwed up with this?

EDIT

Just for completeness, this is the guide I have been basing part of my structure off - [Dockerizing Flask with Postgres Gunicorn and Nginx](https://testdriven.io/blog/dockerizing-flask-with-postgres-gunicorn-and-nginx/) and this is my `app/__init__.py`

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import LoginManager
import traceback
import logging
from app.config import LogConf, AppConfig
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from time import strftime
import os

if AppConfig.DEBUG:
    import debugpy
    debugpy.listen(("0.0.0.0", 5678))
    debugpy.wait_for_client()



app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='/static')
app.config.from_object("app.config.AppConfig")


logger = logging.getLogger('werkzeug')
logpath = os.path.join(LogConf.LOGPATH, LogConf.LOGFILE )
handler = logging.FileHandler(logpath)
logger.addHandler(handler)

Bootstrap(app)
app.config['BOOTSTRAP_SERVE_LOCAL'] = True


db = SQLAlchemy(app)
db.init_app(app)


login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)

from app.routes.core import core
from app.routes.auth import auth


@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    timestamp = strftime('[%Y-%b-%d %H:%M]')
    logger.error('%s %s %s %s %s %s', timestamp, request.remote_addr, request.method, request.scheme, request.full_path, response.status)
    return response


@app.errorhandler(Exception)
def exceptions(e):
    tb = traceback.format_exc()
    timestamp = strftime('[%Y-%b-%d %H:%M]')
    logger.error('%s %s %s %s %s 5xx INTERNAL SERVER ERROR\n%s', timestamp, request.remote_addr, request.method, request.scheme, request.full_path, tb)
    return "Error was logged"


app.register_blueprint(core)
app.register_blueprint(auth)
```

EDIT 2 - Running manage.py no args

```
/app $ python manage.py 
Error: Could not import 'web'.

Usage: manage.py [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

Options:
  --version  Show the flask version
  --help     Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  create_db
  db         Perform database migrations.
  drop_db
  routes     Show the routes for the app.
  run        Run a development server.
  shell      Run a shell in the app context.
/app $
```

Comment: The guide you linked doesn't call for an `__init__.py` in `web`, so, remove it. Also just run `manage.py` from the same directory, it's important because your `PYTHONPATH` defaults to include your current directory. 
Finally, I'm really confused why there isn't a stack trace to this import error, try just `python manage.py` and see what error you get

Comment: Thanks @Macattack, I've removed the file and run again, see updated post

Comment: try doing `export FLASK_APP=app/__init__.py` before running `python manage.py`

Comment: export `FLASK_APP=app/__init__.py` fixed it, my `env` files had it set to export `FLASK_APP=web/__init__.py`. Cheers for the help guys